# Need advice on question edit that invalidates my answer

Tags: discussion, edits

Here is the question:

[Wild Cards * in If Else Statements - Batch Scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44888334/773113)

The OP asked one thing, (which was kind of lame to begin with, but never mind,) I answered, then the OP asked me to look at updated question, and the updated question is like a completely different thing.

So, I rolled back the edit, but I thought I would ask here, because I am not sure what is the right thing to do in situations like this.

I looked at a couple of similar questions here on meta, and it seems like what I did was okay, but I want to make sure.

**Note regarding the possible duplicate:** the OP did not add a *follow-up question*, he edited his question thinking that he was clarifying it, and in doing so it became apparent that his *real* problem was of a different nature than the original question was asking (and my answer was answering.)

Answer (score 8):

What you did is correct. Editing a question so that the provided answers are invalid is not the right way for the original user to get assistance. If they have further questions, they should post a *new* question, not invalidate the help they've already been given.

A single roll back and comment explaining why (as you did) is appropriate.